# Selenium click hidden button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to control webpage with selenium and python

## Python code;

```
menu = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".nav")
hidden = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Soluton')
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class=\"two-columns\"]")
Option 1: ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden)
Option 2 : ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element).click(hidden)
```

---

## html code;

[image: Please visit this image]

I want to click "Solution" button under the nav menu.

However, Solution be in under the nav menu. So it's hidden.

**so, I type following codes ;**

#### Option 1:

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(menu).click(hidden)
```

#### Option 2 :

```
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(element).click(hidden)
```

---

But selenium not happen anything and not give any error message.
How can I click a button under nav menu with selenium ?

Thanks

Comment: Although I'm not completely certain, from what I can guess at through the html, you might have to click on the .icon-ellipsis-h to make the sub actions menu visible. Can't really say much though, since I'm assuming most of the hover-visibility stuff is controlled through javascript on that page.

Comment: @WiggyA. thanks. i tried only find <a href element. i missed <i object. resolved my issue

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your `Question` and your `Requirement` we need to `Mouse Hover` over the `WebElement` with text as **`Actions`** where 2 options pops out as **`Request`** and **`Solution`** and you want to `click()` on **`Solution`**. To achieve that you can use the following code block :

```
#import
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
#code block
menu = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='incident-action']/i[@class='icon-ellipsis-h']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(menu).perform()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='action-list' and @id='header-actions-list']//a[@class='icon-arrow' and contains(text(),'Solution')]").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to click `Actions` to make actions list visible and then click on required `Solution` option:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

actions = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Actions")))
actions.click()
solution = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Solution")))
solution.click()
```